# Setting text color in a flipper

Tags: android, textview, viewflipper

I am using a flipper where in there are like 50 text views..I want to set a color to all of them..how do I do that in 1 shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set a style or theme for the whole activity like

```
<style name="CustomTheme">    
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

And you can set this style to your activity like

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

The docs from google will give moe idea and examples
    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Its telling that the resource is not found, </activity>
   <activity android:name=".Fun" 
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@values/textcolor">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="nik.trivia.FUNTWOANDHALF" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>

Comment: your setting the theme wrong. android:theme="@style/textcolor". You should set it from the style as shown above. If you are still getting issues update your question with the stack trace.